# Kendo Grid - Won't bind to remote data MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Maddening... Trying to utilize AJAX reads with a Kendo Grid.  I've done quite a few binding to data passed down from the model.  I copy the code straight from the KendoUI site and tweak to meet my demands:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<FaultReport2.Models.usp_CMC_TopIssues_Result>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.description).Title("Description");
    columns.Bound(p => p.responsible).Title("Responsibility");
    columns.Bound(p => p.charged_time).Title("Time");
    columns.Bound(p => p.responsible).Title("Responsible");
    columns.Bound(p => p.root_cause).Title("Root Cause");
    columns.Bound(p => p.counter_measure).Title("Countermeasure");
    columns.Bound(p => p.status).Title("Status");
})
.Pageable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(10)
    .Read(read => read
        .Action("cmcTopIssues", "FaultInfo", new { equipment_id = Model.area_id, start_date = Model.start_date })
    )
)
```

)

Controller code for the read.Action():

```
        public ActionResult cmcTopIssues(int equipment_id, DateTime start_date)
    {
        var db = new Models.FAULTEntities1();

        var top_issues = db.usp_CMC_TopIssues(equipment_id, start_date).ToList();

        return Json(top_issues, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Does not work.  I verify that my cmcTopIssues method is being called and that the top_issues var is being filled.  It just does not populate the grid.

When I switch over to local and pass the data down through the model, it works fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, perhaps try modifying your action method as shown in [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding) so that you return a Kendo data source result instead:

```
public ActionResult cmcTopIssues([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, int equipment_id, DateTime start_date)
{
    var db = new Models.FAULTEntities1();

    var top_issues = db.usp_CMC_TopIssues(equipment_id, start_date).AsEnumerable();

    return Json(top_issues.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am positive.  It fires the controller action properly in debug.  Similar syntax is used to do the same thing with Charts and other "controls".  Here is a link to the documentation I am referring to.  Look at the MVC example of Remote Binding.